# CakePHP Search between 2 Date Records

Tags: cakephp, search, date, between

I am building a small Web App that lets users reserve Office Rooms and Equipment. For the Reservation they enter a Start and an End Date.

When a user tries to find out if any (for example) car is available on 2012-10-23, and the database holds reservation date records of Start: `2012-10-20` and End: `2012-10-25` for (lets say) all the cars, how do I include all the dates between my date entries in the search?

The `$date` variable gets it's value from the Date Search Form Field.

This, unfortunately does not work, and I can't figure out how to use daysAsSql for this query:

```
$conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        '? BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($date,'Equipment.date_start','Equipment.date_end'), 
    )));

$this->set('equipments', $this->Equipment->find('all', $conditions));
```

Comment: You should check that the date should not be within `startdate` and `enddate`. http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/06/30/between-and-sql-syntax-in-cakephp/

Comment: Based on the Link you provided, I changed the code to this:

`
'? BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($date,'Equipment.date_start','Equipment.date_end'),
`

Unfortunately that doesn't do anything …

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a simpler solution to this, but thanks for the help:

(As a condition in the find:)

```
array('Equipment.date_start <= ' => $date,
      'Equipment.date_end >= ' => $date
     ),
```

Answer (score 3):

In case if you have one date and you want to use BETWEEN

```
$date_start = start date;
$date_end = date_end;

$conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'date(Equipment.create) BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($date_start, $date_end), 
    )));

$this->set('equipments', $this->Equipment->find('all', $conditions));
```

This is the case if you have From AND To

in your case

```
$date_start = start date;
$date_end = date_end;

$conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Equipment.start_date >=' => array($date_start), 
        'Equipment.end_date <=' => array($date_end)
    ));

$this->set('equipments', $this->Equipment->find('all', $conditions));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is `CakePHP BETWEEN` query example.

I'm defining my arrays as variables, and then using those variables in my CakePHP find function call:

```
// just return these two fields
$fields = array('uri', 'page_views');

// use this "between" range
$conditions = array('Event.date BETWEEN ? and ?' => array($start_date, $end_date));

// run the "select between" query
$results = $this->Event->find('all', 
         array('fields'=>$fields, 
               'conditions'=>$conditions));
```

[Ref from](http://alvinalexander.com/php/cakephp-find-between-select-query-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

```
$start = date('Y-m-d');
$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));

$conditions = array('Event.start <=' => $end, 'Event.end >=' => $start);

$this->Event->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

Comment: i'm just curious - can't find anything about `dateRange` or start / end in docs, api or code, can you please provide a link?

Comment: http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/06/30/between-and-sql-syntax-in-cakephp/    Refer this also

Answer (score 1):

If you are on cakephp 2.0 this is the answer http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper::daysAsSql

If you are on cakephp 1.3 you can use TimeHelper, just import it and use the same function as per example in documentation here http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1471/Formatting

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the docs, but I can't get daysAsSql to work with this. (I am on CakePHP 2)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use database columns with this `BETWEEN`-syntax. If you assign strings in the array, CakePHP will quote them. Same for numeric values depending on your database setup.

> CakePHP will quote the numeric values depending on the field type in your DB.
>   – see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions

If you still want to use the `BETWEEN`, you can write your queries into the array key because CakePHP will not escape the keys, but only the values.

> CakePHP only escapes the array values. You should **never** put user data into the keys. Doing so will make you vulnerable to SQL injections.
>   – see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions

Concerning your problem:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        '"YYYY-MM-DD" BETWEEN Model.date_start AND Model.date_end',
    ),
));
```

You can even work with MySQL date and time functions:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'CURDATE() BETWEEN Model.date_start AND Model.date_end',
    ),
));
```

If you use date/time functions, do not quote them. If you use a specific date put it in quotes.