# Cakephp MYSQL query: SELECT where date is greater than

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, cakephp

I have to run a `MYSQL` select query where the query returns all values that have the beginning date 10 days after today. I have tried these two methods none of which seem to work, where do I need to make a change?

```
$fix_d_table = TableRegistry::get('fixed_departures');
$f_dates_march = $fix_d_table   ->find("all")
    ->where(['trek_id' => 3])
    ->andWhere(['month(date_from)' => 03])
    ->andWhere(['date_from' >= date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+10 days"))])
    ->order(['date_from'=>'asc'])
    ->select(['date_from', 'date_to', 'seats_available','id'])
    ->toArray();

$fix_d_table = TableRegistry::get('fixed_departures');
$f_dates_march = $fix_d_table   ->find("all")
    ->where(['trek_id' => 3])
    ->andWhere(['month(date_from)' => 03])
    ->andWhere(['date(date_from)' >= date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+10 days"))])
    ->order(['date_from'=>'asc'])
    ->select(['date_from', 'date_to', 'seats_available','id'])
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: Refere [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899211/cakephp-search-between-2-date-records)

Comment: I'd be tempted to find a working query in raw MySQL, and the re-engineer it to suit your framework

Answer (score 1):

Try below one

```
$fix_d_table = TableRegistry::get('fixed_departures'); $f_dates_march
= $fix_d_table   ->find("all")
    ->where(['trek_id' => 3])
    ->andWhere(
        function ($exp) {
            return $exp->or_([
                'date_from <=' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+10 days")),
                'date_from >=' => date('Y-m-d')
            ]);
    })
    ->order(['date_from'=>'asc'])
    ->select(['date_from', 'date_to', 'seats_available','id'])
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
'date_from >=' => date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+10 days"))
```

if you can rely on mysql server date you can use NOW() inside your query

```
 ->where(function($exp, $q) {
        return $exp->gte($q->func()->dateDiff([
            'date_from ' => 'identifier',
            $q->func()->now() ]),  10);
    });
```

this will give you the following SQL condition

```
WHERE 
(
  DATEDIFF(date_from , NOW())
)  >= 10
```

Comment: I used to have things like `NOW()` in my queries, but have removed them all in order to better support unit testing, which sometimes requires that "now" be set to a specific date and/or time. My queries now look more like `'date_from >=' => FrozenDate::now()->addDays(10)`.