# Retreive interval data from database difference between two date

Tags: php, date, cakephp

I have a table named `TestingLogDevice`. Table column name `dateee`. 
Table `dateee` field value looks like this.

```
id   dateee
 1   01-11-18
 2   01-11-18
 3   01-11-18
 4   01-11-18
 5   31-11-18
 6   31-11-18
 7   31-11-18
 8   31-11-18
 9   31-11-18
 10  30-11-18
 11  30-11-18
 12  29-11-18
 13  28-11-18
 14  28-11-18
 15  27-10-18
```

I have a form looks like this. When I submit this form value. Then I get this value looks like this

[image: ![Form Image]

```
Array
(
    [precise_chart_val] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [start_date] => 30-10-18
            [end_date] => 01-11-18
        )

)
```

I retrieve the value two date difference from table `TestingLogDevice` using this code. I follow this link
[Tutorial Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899211/cakephp-search-between-2-date-records)

```
$start_date  =  $data['precise_chart_val']['start_date'];
$end_date    =  $data['precise_chart_val']['end_date'];

$conditions  = array('TestingLogDevice.dateee BETWEEN ? and ?' => array($start_date, $end_date));


$this->set('datas',
    $this->TestingLogDevice->find('all', 
         array(
             'conditions' =>array($conditions, 'TestingLogDevice.Siteid'=>$testing_log_device_site_name),
             'order'      => array('id' => 'desc')
         )
    )
);
```

But when I print `datas` I get all value of `dateee` field from id **1 to 15**. But I get only data from id 1 to 11. Where I'm wrong? I don't fix it.

Comment: What is the data type of the `dateee` column? If it is a text type, you want to go and fix that mistake first of all.

Comment: my `dateee` field is vachar.

Comment: Then you should really change that first of all - so that it uses a proper Date type.

Answer (score 0):

> my dateee field is vachar.

You are getting this result because of your dateee field datatype. To solve this problem Either change data type from varchar to datetime

**OR**

Change

```
$conditions  = array('TestingLogDevice.dateee BETWEEN ? and ?' => array($start_date, $end_date));
```

**To**

```
 $conditions  = array("date_format(str_to_date(TestingLogDevice.dateee, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN ? and ?" => array($start_date, $end_date));
```

[mySQL convert varchar to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date)